# How to get file size in nodejs as async await?

Tags: node.js, async-await, fs, stat

How to get file size in nodejs as async await ?

Here is the code for video streaming with nodejs . (and we are looking optimized performing video streaming idea's for mobile back-end API )

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

app.get("/video", async (req, res) => {
  const path = "assets/sample.mp4";
  const stat = await fs.stat(path);  // here is the issue 
  const fileSize = stat.size;
  const range = req.headers.range;

  if (range) {
    const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
    const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
    const end = parts[1] ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : fileSize - 1;

    if (start >= fileSize) {
      res
        .status(416)
        .send("Requested range not satisfiable\n" + start + " >= " + fileSize);
      return;
    }

    const chunksize = end - start + 1;
    const file = fs.createReadStream(path, { start, end });
    const head = {
      "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
      "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
      "Content-Length": chunksize,
      "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
    };

    res.writeHead(206, head);
    file.pipe(res);
  } else {
    const head = {
      "Content-Length": fileSize,
      "Content-Type": "video/mp4"
    };
    res.writeHead(200, head);
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
  }
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Listening on port 3000!");
});
```

This code have an issue on `const stat=await fs.stat(path);` ,

The synchronizes code working fine here like `const stat=await fs.statSync(path);`

how to write the `fs.stat();` asynchronous ? Or any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `promises`version to use `async/await`. change your require to

```
const fs = require("fs").promises;
```

The default is callback style.

Comment: ```
 await fs.stat(path);
``` 

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'stat' of undefined

Comment: typo in the casing. it should be `promises` not `Promises`.. updated answer

Comment: it is `promises`  with a small p.

Comment: Its working Great !

fs.createReadStream() not working with require("fs").promises !

Comment: This is the right answer but the question not how to get fs but how to get the size.

The complete answer is :
```
   const fs = require("fs").promises;
   let size = (await fs.stat(path)).size
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to Promisify `fs.stat` and then use it in an async manner. 
You can use this. `util.promisify()`

To make a callback method return promises, you can do this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);
const { promisify } = require("util");

async function main() {
    await writeFile("/tmp/test4.js",
        "console.log('Hello world with promisify and async/await!');");

    console.info("file created successfully with promisify and async/await!");
}

main().catch(error => console.error(error));
```

You can check out this [link](https://dev.to/mrm8488/from-callbacks-to-fspromises-to-handle-the-file-system-in-nodejs-56p2) for references.

Answer (score 1):

May be different ans but will help you.

As you said you are optimising performing video steaming.

So website like youtube use UDP instead of TCP. You can learn about UDP [Here](https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/UDP-User-Datagram-Protocol) . 
If you are using node js then you can implement it using sockets

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('Socket connected: '+socket);   
    io.sockets.emit('msgFromAdmin', 'Hello client, this message sent from admin');
    // call our main handler 
    streamer(socket);

}); 

/*
initializes ffmpeg child process which will listen on udp port:33333 for incoming frames of stream
forward video stream to client.html through socket.io
*/
var streamer = function (socket) {  

    var ffmpeg = require('child_process').spawn("/vagrant/nodejs-ffmpeg-livestreamer/ffmpeg-source/ffmpeg", ["-re","-y","-i", "udp://127.0.0.1:33333", "-f", "mjpeg", "-s","500x500","-pix_fmt","rgb24","pipe:1"]);

    ffmpeg.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    ffmpeg.on('close', function (code) {
        console.log('ffmpeg exited with code ' + code);
    });

    ffmpeg.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });

    ffmpeg.stdout.on('data', function (data) {

        var frame = new Buffer(data).toString('base64');
        socket.emit('render',frame);
    });

};
```

#### Not have time to write code so This was code is copied from Online

FOr Full code you can visit [Here](https://github.com/gaditek-alikhan/nodejs-ffmpeg-livestreamer-video-streaming/blob/master/server.js)

Answer (score 1):

```sh
npm i file_size_url
```

```js
import file_size_url from 'file_size_url';

file_size_url("https://server10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/001.mp3")
    .then(console.log) // 968.27 KB
    .catch(console.error);
```

OR

```js
import file_size_url from 'file_size_url';

let size = await file_size_url("https://serverjyy10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/0001.mp3")
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))

console.log(size) // 968.27 KB
```

Example for lop

```js
let array = [

    'https://server10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/001.mp3',
    'https://server10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/002.mp3',
    'https://server10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/003.mp3',
    'https://server10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/055.mp3',
    'https://server10.mp3quran.net/bader/Rewayat-Hafs-A-n-Assem/110.mp3',

]

for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {

    try {

        let fies_size = await file_size_url(array[index])

        if (fies_size.toString().split('.')[0] <= 95 && fies_size.toString().split(' ')[1] === 'MB') {

            console.log(fies_size + ' || <= 95 MB');

        }

        else if (fies_size.toString().split('.')[0] > 95 && fies_size.toString().split(' ')[1] === 'MB') {

            console.log(fies_size + ' || > 95 MB');

        }

        else if (fies_size.toString().split(' ')[1] === 'KB') {

            console.log(fies_size + ' || KB');

        }


    } catch (error) {

        console.log(error);

    }

}


/* output 
968.27 KB || KB
170.58 MB || > 95 MB
95.77 MB || <= 95 MB
12.21 MB || <= 95 MB
711.92 KB || KB
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use npm-multer

check this link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: maxSize }
}).single('bestand');

[How to limit the file size when uploading with multer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697502/how-to-limit-the-file-size-when-uploading-with-multer)