# Uploadig multiple files with different requirements in multer

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, multer

I have a route that expects a multipart form and in this multipart form, there are two files that are going to be uploaded.

1- a video file that should have a size limit of 2GB and is going to be directly saved on disk in `public/videos`

2- a thumbnail which is an image that should have a size limit of 20MB and is going to be saved in memory to be resized with sharp and saved into a different directory which is `public/video/thumbnails`

I tried to use `upload.fields([ { name: 'video', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'thumbnail', maxCount: 1 } ])` . but it doesn't satisfy. These two files should have different size limits and I want one to be stored in disk directly and the other one in memory.

It looks like I need two different `multer().single()` on the same route.

Is it possible with multer to do this? or any other multipart parsers?

Comment: I was having same issue. Hope this thread will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641991/14561228