# Multer does not throw an error or trigger error handlers on file size limit exceed

Tags: express, multer

I am using Multer to upload a single file, I tried using the limits option but it didn't work, I instead tried a middleware function that detects if a file over the limit:

```js
const uploadMiddleware = (req, res, next) =>
  multer({ storage: grid, limits: { fileSize: 4000000 } }).single("file")(req, res, () => {
    if (req.file.size > 4000000) {
      return res.status(413).send("Exceeded file size limit, upload cancelled.");
    }

    return next();
});
```

This method requires the file to actually be uploaded to the storage destination before it runs which won't do since I want to prevent these files from being uploaded in the first place. What am I doing wrong?

(I already tried the solutions on [How to limit the file size when uploading with multer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697502/how-to-limit-the-file-size-when-uploading-with-multer), they don't work for me and simply cause the page to freeze without throwing errors.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit the file size when uploading with multer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697502/how-to-limit-the-file-size-when-uploading-with-multer)

Comment: I tried all of the solutions on that question and they didn't help, the content-length solution won't do since it can be manipulated by the client.

Comment: Every HTTP request can be manipulated (think CURL). The only way is to check file size when the upload is finished.

Comment: Seems like this is a known [issue](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/602), but it doesn't seem like it will be fixed soon.